# External JS Files Working in Angular 7 But Not in 8

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, stl-format

I'm trying to run [these viewstl](https://www.viewstl.com/plugin/#install) javascript files in an Angular 8 application. I've run it successfully in an Angular 6 and 7 application by doing the following basics:

- Copied the .js files to the application, keeping the web worker files (`load_stl.min.js` and `parser.min.js`) in the root directory and the rest of the files in `assets/scripts`.
- Add the .js files to my scripts array in angular.json in this working order

  ```json
  "scripts": 
  [            
        "src/assets/scripts/three.min.js",
        "src/assets/scripts/webgl_detector.js",
        "src/assets/scripts/Projector.js",
        "src/assets/scripts/CanvasRenderer.js",
        "src/assets/scripts/OrbitControls.js",
        "src/assets/scripts/stl_viewer.min.js"          
  ]
  ```
- Added the necessary code to the template:

  `html <div id="stl_container"></div>`

- Lastly referencing `stl_viewer.min.js` from the component:

  ```js
  declare var StlViewer:any;
  var stl_viewer = new StlViewer(document.getElementById('stl_container'), { models: [ {id:0, filename:"assets/_somefile.stl"} ] });
  ```

As I mentioned, it works fine in Angular 6 but when running from Angular 8 I get the error as soon as the javascript is initialized from the component - and I don't understand why.

> GET http://localhost:4300/load_stl.min.js 404 (Not Found)

I'm not necessarily sure if the version difference could be the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is an extra property on the StlViewer class called `load_three_files` which takes the path to all the javascript files as argument.

Moving `parser.min` and `load_stl.min` to the assets/script folder and adding `load_three_files: "assets/scripts/"` to StlViewer fixed it.